# How to setup auto-deletion of log and telemetry data on a Heila Edge device to maintain disk space?

Tags: logging, service, cron, telemetry, auto-delete

Old logs and telemetry data often take up disk space. How to setup auto-deletion of log and telemetry data to avoid this?

I tried to create a service that gets triggered at a certain frequency, be it once every day or week, to delete telemetry data and a cron job to delete logs. I expected that it would delete logs and telemetry data as required.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/HeilaTechnologies/device-comissioning/tree/master/auto-delete

In this link, you'll find documentation on how to set up auto-deletion of log and telemetry data along with a zip file containing all the files required to create and trigger a service and a cron job.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).